# How can I push images from a folder into an array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, image, jpeg, getfiles

This is my first time posting a question to stack overflow but I will try my best to explain it. I am trying to load .jpg info from a folder on my server to an Array with each image going to a different location. Currently, I can get just jpg images but they all go to image[0]. I'm trying to do this with nodejs and fs if possible.

The code is:

```
 const fs = require("fs");

 function getFolderFiles(path, extension) {
     let files = fs.readdirSync(path);
     return files.filter((file) =>
       file.match(new RegExp(`.*\.(${extension})`, "ig"))
     );
 }

 console.log(getFolderFiles("./broll", ".jpg"));
 images = [getFolderFiles("./broll", ".jpg")];
 console.log(images[0]);
```

It currently kicks out

```
[ 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg' ]
[ 'image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg' ]
```

I am trying to get console.log (images[0]);  to = image1.jpg and so on.

My end goal is to return something like the below but I will work on the other info after I figure out how to get the array setup.

```
 // var images = [
 //   {
 //     path: "./broll/image1.jpg",
 //     caption: captions,
 //     loop: imagelength,
 //   },
```

I have been scouring the internet and can't find a solution that is something that I understand as I am relatively new to programming.

Comment: Did you ever try to omit the square brackets in your second to last line?

Comment: ... Because this is what will create a new array where your expected array is added at index 0

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the construction of the regex is wrong, because when you pass pass a string to the `RegExp` constructor, you have to escape the `\`  to make it show up in the regex, ie

```
new RegExp(`.*\\.(${extension})`, "ig")
```

But if you do that, you will get the following `RegExp`

```
new RegExp(`.*\\..jpg`, "ig");
```

Ie, an arbitrary (maybe empty) string  (matched by `.*`), followed by a literal `.` (matched by `\\.`) followed by an arbitrary character (matched by `.`), followed by literally `jpg`. And you are also missing word anchors, ie your regex will also match something like `foo.ajpg.bar`

A better approach would be defining your regexp as

```
new RegExp(`.+\\.${extension}$`, "ig")
```

and passing only `jpg`  (ie without the dot) as extension. This will match an arbitrary string of at least length 1 (`.+`) followed by a `.` (`\\.`) followed by your extension *at the end* of the word (matched by `$`)

Second, when you do

```
images = [getFolderFiles("./broll", ".jpg")];
```

You are creating a new array, with the result of `getFolderFiles` being the first element of that array. But as the result of `getFolderFiles` already is an array, you end up with the following structure

```
[["image0.jpg", "image1.jpg"]]
```

You probably just want

```
images = getFolderFiles("./broll", "jpg");
```

Comment: @SyntheticTV If that answer helped you, don't hesitate to upvote and/or accept it ...